# getting compile Errors after run Pod install

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, cocoapods-app

I had some libraries in my project, but after I run `pod install` I get some ***compile errors***, those Libraries were already installed with their specific version and were working fine before.
this is the errors:
[XCode Pods compile errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqdqv.jpg)

Most errors are comming from ***SideMenu*** and ***DropDown*** Pods.

this is my dependencies

```
    pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 5'
    pod 'RxSwift', '~> 5'
    
    #pod 'Fabric'
    #pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'DropDown', '2.3.13'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
    pod 'SnapKit', '~> 5.0.0'
    pod 'BrightFutures', '~> 8.0.0'
    pod 'Result', '~> 5.0'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.4'
    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.3.2'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 2.2.5'
    pod 'SideMenu', '~> 6.4.7'
    pod 'SAMKeychain', '~> 1.5.3'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.3.3'
    pod 'YapDatabase', '~> 3.0.2'
```

Note: I also tried to run `pod install --no-repo-update` but still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `Derived Data` or Clean Build Folder

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine after I removed the content of **Pods** Folder inside my project then run `pod install`